# What's the difference between "moustique" and "maringouin"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, québec, zoologie

I always thought that both words referred to the same insect: the mosquito.  However, I was recently reading *Jean Rivard, le défricheur* by Antoine Gérin-Lajoie (19th century Québécois author), and on page 167, he writes,

> Mais puisque j’ai promis de dire la vérité, toute la vérité, je ne dois pas omettre de mentionner ici une plaie de la vie des bois durant la belle saison ; un mal, pour me servir des expressions du fabuliste en parlant de la peste,
>
> *Un mal qui répand la terreur
>
> Et que le ciel dans sa fureur
>
> Inventa pour punir les crimes de la terre...*
>
> Je veux parler des maringouins.
>
> Durant les mois de mai et de juin, ces insectes incommodes, sanguinaires, suivis bientôt des moustiques et des brûlots, s’attaquent jour et nuit à la peau du malheureux défricheur.

This quote makes it sound like the "maringouins" were followed by "moustiques," indicating that they are not the same insect.

Am I misreading this passage, or is there a difference (and if there is a difference, what is it)?

Comment: The usage is likely to be different in different parts of *francophonie*. Where I'm from (northern half of France), *maringouin* just isn't used. It seems to designate different sets of insects in different regions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il y a un ordre d'insectes, les [diptères](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diptera), qui se divise en deux sous-ordres, les [nématocères](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nematocera) qui sont nous dit *Wikipédia* comme des moucherons/moustiques, et les [brachycères](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachycera) qui sont davantage comme des mouches (le [taon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabanidae) ou *mouche à cheval/chevreuil*, par exemple). **Au Québec** aujourd'hui on peut entendre en langue courante « maringouin » pour le [moustique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870142) (GDT), insecte du premier sous-ordre (auquel appartient aussi le [brûlot](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceratopogonidae)), plus particulièrement un [culicidé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moustique) ; on ne connaissait pas le terme *cousin*...

Une des mouches usuelles au Québec qui mord littéralement au lieu de piquer et dont on n'a pas discuté ce pourrait être ce qu'on appelle une « mouche noire », une [simulie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulie), moucheron appelé aussi parfois *arabi*, *alambi* ou *mouche de Beynes* (Wikipédia), appartenant au premier sous-ordre (à ne pas confondre avec la [*mouche grise de la viande*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcophaga_carnaria), du deuxième sous-ordre, à laquelle on fait parfois référence avec le vernaculaire [*mouche à merde*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouche_%C3%A0_merde)). On ne sait pas si ça correspondrait à la séquence présentée (maringouin, moustique, brûlot) ni si la séquence serait la même aujourd'hui (climat...). Le *Glossaire du parler français au Canada* (1930) a une entrée pour *moustique* mais pas *maringouin*, et réfère à l'entrée *mouche* à plusieurs types : *mouche noire, mouche à cheval/chevaux, mouche à cornes, mouche à patates, mouche à vers*. On n'est pas plus avancé ; le choix dans l'extrait pourrait être purement idiosyncratique et personnellement je ne sais pas à quoi on réfère exactement...

---

**Ces affirmations ne permettent pas de déterminer à quoi fait référence le terme *moustique* (par opposition à maringouin) dans l'extrait...**

Comment: @rotaredom Howdy! You have selected my answer, thank you. The content may be useful and it may answer the Q. from the title in today's Qc French yet it does not provide the answer as to what the author might have meant by _moustique_ in the quote as opposed to _maringouin_. Please consider unaccepting the answer so that your Q. remains in the unanswered queue to attract further answers down the road. It is entirely up to you. I haven't looked at the book, do you remember any mention of a region or city, for instance _Laurentides_ or Eastern Qc. by any chance? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*Moustique* is the generic word used everywhere while *maringouin* is an alternative name used only in Canada, Louisiana, French Guyana  and Caribbeans French speaking islands. *Maringouin* [might also be used](http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/maringouin.html) to name flies and similar insects:

> Par extension, ce mot désigne parfois d'autres types de nuisibles comme les mouches ou d'autres insectes volants.

Here, the author makes a distinction between three varieties of flying insects as the *brûlots* are also a kind of mosquitoes (small ones) but there is no way to guess what distinction he makes between *moustiques* and *maringouins*. According to Peter Shor's experience, they might have been *mouches noires*.

Here is [a blog](http://linguistiquement-correct.blogspot.fr/2011/06/maringouin.html) that challenges the admitted *maringouin* etymology.

Comment: Then am I misunderstanding the quote?  What does the author mean by distinguishing between the two?

Comment: What do you base this on? Both [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maringouin) and [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maringouin) suggest that it can sometimes mean any mosquito and sometimes a different kind of insect (known as *cousin* in my part of the world — but that's not the one in the question since these don't sting) and sometimes different sets of insects but they aren't clear about who uses what meaning.

Comment: @Gilles You are right. *Maringouins* might not be mosquitoes here.

Comment: Article intéressant sur l'étymologie ! À le lire peut-être qu'au final le maringouin de Rivard était le moucheron noir, et son moustique, le maringouin ! Merci !

Comment: I doubt *maringouins* are mosquitoes. I've visited the woods of Vermont (just south of Québec) during blackfly season, and can personally testify that  blackflies (*les mouches noires*) only bite during the months of May and June, as Gérin-Lajoie says, whereas mosquitoes bite during the entire summer. (And I've checked this on the internet, and the season is roughly the same in Québec).

Comment: @PeterShor What the author calls *maringouins* are not *moustiques*. They might be indeed *mouches noires* according to your experience. Mosquitoes are called *maringouins* in Québec but by extension, other kind of insects might also be called that way. It's a little similar to "bug" in English which can be a true bug (*punaise*), a beetle (*coccinelle*) or whatever small insect.

Answer (score 2):

[Une réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29471) a déjà fait un bon tour de la nomenclature des insectes sanguinaires du Québec. J’y ajouterai une confirmation de première main que l’ordre *maringouin – mouche noire – brûlot* est le bon, depuis mon enfance et jusqu’à aujourd’hui, et qu’il demeure aussi valide en allant vers l’ouest jusqu’aux Rocheuses, de la frontière avec les États-Unis jusqu’aux confins nordiques du continent, juste au sud des îles arctiques. Je suppose sans problème qu’il était le même il y a un siècle, les conditions hydrographiques suivant la fonte des neiges suivant vraisemblablement la même séquence aujourd’hui qu’alors.

Comme l’indique l’auteur de la réponse, cependant, tout cela n’explique pas pourquoi les maringouins sont distingués des moustiques dans la citation, et je n’ai pas non plus de réponse absolue à offrir ici, simplement une hypothèse à émettre, hypothèse qui ne sera malheureusement pas avare de présuppositions que d’aucuns pourront juger irrecevables. Je l’offre néanmoins en attendant une meilleure solution...

---

**Hypothèse**

• Il fut un temps où le terme *maringouin*, inusité en Europe, supplanta celui de *moustique* dans l’usage oral Canadien-Français, pour désigner l’insecte que l’on connaît aujourd’hui indifféremment sous les deux appellations. Qu’un mot en remplace un autre est un phénomène avéré quoique rare, bien que sa rareté ne soit pas extrême. Les raisons varient cependant, et toute conjecture sur les raisons qui auraient assuré la promotion de *maringouin* aux dépens de *moustique* serait de ma part hasardeuse et ici inutile.

• *Moustique* devient alors un terme libre, libre de s’appliquer à un autre type d’insecte ennuyant, la mouche noire, la grande absente de la liste citée par Gérin-Lajoie, cette plaie des forêts québécoises en juin et juillet, et que l’on serait bien en peine d’essayer d’oublier lorsqu’arrive son temps de l’année.

Pourquoi supposerais-je que **la** moustique (*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*) ait selon l’auteur été un terme désignant la mouche noire ?

La première et plus importante raison est l’ordre d’apparition de leurs populations après l’hiver, hypothèse formulée dans la réponse liée en début de réponse et confirmée ci-dessus par moi-même, d’après mon expérience personnelle d’enfant de la campagne abitibienne et de travailleur de terrain ayant fréquenté ces hostiles milieux de la taïga et de la toundra canadienne depuis plus de vingt ans.

Ma seconde raison est plus spéculative. Les cadres de moustiquaires attachés¹ aux fenêtres des maisons nord-américaines datent, [paraît-il](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_screen#History), de la première moitié du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, on peut donc penser que de longue date les gens en ont fait usage dans leur maison, afin de se protéger convenablement de l’appétit féroce des maringouins, particulièrement actifs la nuit et à l’aube et gâchant avec une étourdissante efficacité le sommeil des justes et des autres. Mais il est un fait que tout un chacun ayant séjourné dans les campagnes québécoises en été pourra confirmer : les mouches noires, nuées d’une extrême agressivité au grand air, sont d’une remarquable tranquillité aussitôt arrivées à l’intérieur des maisons, même celles dont on laisse les portes ouvertes. Les mouches noires forment alors une colonie dans les fenêtres ou moustiquaires, où les enfants (petits et grands), peuvent les écrabouiller l’une après l’autre sans devoir même se presser. Leur comportement en ceci est fort différent de celui du maringouin, qui ne se formalise guère d’un séjour à l’intérieur des maisons. Si l’on considère que le moustiquaire tire son nom du fait qu’il protège contre les moustiques *(maringouins)*, que l’on observe ensuite qu’il s’y forme des colonies de mouches noires, et que le terme *moustique* est désormais libre, pourquoi ce dernier ne pourrait-il pas alors s’appliquer aux mouches noires ?

C’est très hypothétique, mais j’illustre cependant le fait qu’un nom animal devenu libre peut s’appliquer à un nouvel animal apparenté en mentionnant le cas du [chevreuil](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevreuil), qui est un animal présent en Europe mais pas en Amérique. Quand les premiers colons européens francophones sont arrivés en Amérique, l’attribution du nom *chevreuil* au *cerf de Virginie* n’a guère posé de problème majeur, et s’est d’ailleurs perpétué jusqu’à ce jour. Les spécialistes et ceux qui voyagent fréquemment de part et d’autre de l’Atlantique (groupes auxquels nous pouvons ajouter celui des puristes) feront la distinction et utiliseront les termes exacts, mais elle ne sera pas nécessaire dans la plupart des cas...

Les conséquences des deux dernières parties de l’hypothèse sont aujourd’hui faciles à valider. <sub>(La **ré**apparition du doublon n’est pas certaine, on s’entend, mais l’équivalence *maringouin-moustique*, du moins, l’est aujourd’hui...)</sub>

• Éventuellement, le terme *moustique* réapparaît comme synonyme de *maringouin* pour l’ensemble ou peu s’en faut de la population québécoise.

• On s’interroge sur le sens d’une phrase d’Antoine Gérin-Lajoie *(ici...)*   :-)

---

¹ <sub>Le terme est très majoritairement utilisé au masculin au Québec, je m’excuse auprès de ceux que ça choquera.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak from my experience, but here in Quebec, the maringouin is considered to be much bigger than the moustique. The maringouin's body reaches up to a 1.25 inches after a meal, while the moustique barely reaches half an inch. By comparison, the brulot is small enough to slip through the spaces in a window screen, so roughly 1/20th of an inch.

Answer (score 0):

As I often explain to my French friends, the difference between a moustique and maringouin is that the maringouin needs to kneel in order to bite you in the forehead.

Comment: Une source serait la bienvenue.